# Vue 3 global properties are not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'd like to declare a global variable in Vue 3 that can be changed at any time by any component (and by main.js itself) and should be reactive.

My main.js file:

```
const app = createApp(App);

app.config.globalProperties.$myGlobalVariable = {
   content: 'not updated'
};

// simulating something async as an HTTP call
setTimeout(() => {
  app.config.globalProperties.$myGlobalVariable.content = 'updated';
  console.log(app.config.globalProperties.$myGlobalVariable.content); // updated
}, 2000);

app.mount('#app');
```

My component file:

```
<script>
   export default {
      created() {
         setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(this.$myGlobalVariable.content)// updated
         }, 3000);
      }
   }
</script>
<template>
  <main>
    <p>{{ $myGlobalVariable.content }}</p>
  </main>
</template>
```

Inside my component (the `p` element), I only see `not updated`, although the `setTimeout` inside the `created()` function of my component proves that it has changed.
How can I get the value of `$myGlobalVariable.content` to change inside the `p` element?

Comment: A common way is to do this is to declare global state in separate module, https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api . You won't have access to `this` with composition api. globalProperties is needed to expose it in a template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're placing a non reactive object into `globalProperties` and expect it to become reactive. It won't happen.

Vue exposes its reactivity so it can be imported and used anywhere.
Making `$myGlobalVariable` reactive is straight forward and intuitive:

```js
app.config.globalProperties.$myGlobalVariable = reactive({
  content: 'not updated'
})
```

Demo:

```js
const { createApp, reactive } = Vue

const app = createApp()

app.config.globalProperties.$myGlobalVariable = reactive({
  content: 'not updated'
})

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.41/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="$myGlobalVariable.content" />
  <pre v-text="$myGlobalVariable" />
</div>
```